# how can I auto remove attribute ' type="module" crossorigin ' in <script> on vite

Tags: vite

I use vite to build my program and I want that script tag in index.html doesn`t has these attribute 【type="module" crossorigin】。what should I change my vite.config.js[image]

Answer (score 9):

Create a vite plugin to transform your html.

```js
const noAttr = () => {
  return {
    name: "no-attribute",
    transformIndexHtml(html) {
      return html.replace(`type="module" crossorigin`, "");
    }
}

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [noAttr()]
})
```